# Should I add past full time experience for internship

Tags: international-students, internship

I am an international student in Canada. Currently, I am pursuing Master's in Computer Science from a well reputed University and I am incline to apply for summer internships. Before coming to Canada, I have worked professionally four years in India as a software developer. My concern is, should I mention this in my resume for internship? Will it be overkill for internship? I will be applying to similar jobs as my professional experience?

Comment: You might want to try the Workplace stack exchange.

Answer (score 5):

Yes definitely. There is no doubt in mentioning the past experience. Even company s providing the internship also look for such candidates with some prior experience in their respective field. It will enables you to stand apart from the crowd and you could impress employer with such resumes. You dont need to describe the experience briefly as it is a resume.